# Looping through a form's controls; can this be more efficient?

Tags: vb.net, loops

I'm beginning to create a class to easily style my Windows apps. The concept is to just add the reference to the class on Form Load, then have the class automatically style each control on the form according to the properties I have for each control in the style class.

I've created a method where I just pass the Form to it, then loop through each control, check which type it is, then style it accordingly. No problem there so far; the problem is, if the form has a container control on it (i.e. a GroupBox), the items in it *also* need to be looped through, and checked for matches, and styled accordingly. So, if for example, I already have a check for a Button control in the main loop, with all of its style code there, then if the GroupBox has a button within it, it goes unstyled, unless I put the exact same check and style code in *that* loop as well ...

As one can imagine, checking for every single type of control + adding it's style code to each, and then repeating the exact same thing within another loop inside that loop, just to add all the same checks and style code, would turn into a TON of code (not to mention duplicated lines).

I'm wondering if maybe there's a smarter way of doing this, other than moving all of the style code into their own Subs, per control, then duplicating all of the same checks in both loops, and just calling each Sub for the styling? (Which is still messy, but at least all of that control style code isn't duplicated).

Here's the basic code I have right now; for the sake of clarity, I omitted all of the actual styling code per control (where you see the ' Style the control comments in each):

```
Public Sub MyStyle(ByVal zForm As Form, Optional lstIgnoreControl As List(Of Control) = Nothing)

    Try

        ' Form
        With (zForm)
            ' Style the basic Form properties
        End With

    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try

    For Each zCntl As Control In zForm.Controls
        ' Controls

        If zCntl.HasChildren Then
            For Each zChildCntl As Control In zCntl.Controls
                If zChildCntl.GetType Is GetType(CheckBox) Then
                    ' Style the Checkbox
                End If
            Next
        End If

        If IsNothing(lstIgnoreControl) = True OrElse lstIgnoreControl.Contains(zCntl) = False Then

            Select Case zCntl.GetType

                Case GetType(MenuStrip)

                    Try
                        ' Style the menustrip
                    Catch ex As Exception
                    End Try

                Case GetType(StatusStrip)

                    Try
                        ' Style the Statusstrip
                    Catch ex As Exception
                    End Try

                Case GetType(Label)

                    Try
                        ' Style the Label
                    Catch ex As Exception
                    End Try

                Case GetType(LinkLabel)

                    Try
                        ' Style the LinkLabel
                    Catch ex As Exception
                    End Try

                Case GetType(Panel)

                    Try
                        ' Style the Panel
                    Catch ex As Exception
                    End Try

                Case GetType(Button)

                    Try
                        ' Style the Button
                    Catch ex As Exception
                    End Try

                Case GetType(PictureBox)

                    Try
                        ' Style the PictureBox
                    Catch ex As Exception
                    End Try

                Case GetType(DataGridView)

                    Try
                        ' Style the DataGridView
                    Catch ex As Exception
                    End Try

                Case GetType(GroupBox)

                    Try
                        ' Style the GroupBox
                    Catch ex As Exception
                    End Try

                Case GetType(DateTimePicker)

                    Try
                        ' Style the DateTimePicker
                    Catch ex As Exception
                    End Try

            End Select

        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

The `zCntl.HasChildren` loop is the sub loop I'm referring to, where the redundency would all come in, that I'm *hoping* to avoid.

Comment: Could (maybe) be a job for a [pattern visitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern). There is also room for method overloading (a style Sub per control type) and let polymorphism play it's role (in "good" OO style you shouldn't need to do type test). One can also imagine a base class with default styling subs which are overridable by inheritor for custom styling

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr but

```
Iterator Function allControls(c As Control) As IEnumerable(Of Control)
    Yield c
    For Each cc As Control In c.Controls
        For Each ccc In allControls(cc)
            Yield ccc
        Next
    Next
End Function
```

sample use:

```
For Each gb In allControls(zForm).OfType(Of GroupBox)
    ' ...
Next
```

or better put them all in a LookUp:

```
Dim types = allControls(zForm).ToLookup(Function(c) c.GetType)

For Each gb In types(GetType(GroupBox))
    ' ...
Next
```